# Is there a way to check for duplicates in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-3.7

I have a program i need to create and one of the tasks are to have the user input 5 numbers(integer) for each day of the week (Monday-Friday). For those 5 numbers i need to figure out if there are any duplicates  that the user has inputted and display which two days are the duplicates using a single list that contains strings and integers and finally display them. Im new to programming and i would very much appreciate the help!

using python 3.x

Thank you!

Comment: Any progress since [check for duplicates in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59166790/check-for-duplicates-in-a-list)?

Comment: Not as much as i hoped, i kept trying and failing again and again only to mess up the program even more sadly but atleast im learning!

Comment: Can you share what you have so far or outline the specific issues you encounter?

Comment: Have you had a look at the methods that a list has?  And if so, have you tried using any of them?  https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a dictionary to keep track of the days for each number. See the following example:

```py
days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday']

# get numbers
numbers = dict()
for day in days:
    n = input(f'enter number for day {day}: ')
    if n in numbers:
        numbers[n].append(day)
    else:
        numbers[n] = [day]

# find duplicates
for n, ds in numbers.items():
    if len(ds) > 1:
        print(f'duplicate number {n} for days', *ds)
```

Comment: Thank you Diego really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

This one  with collection module :) for big list better . ... .

```
from collections import Counter
z = ['Mo', 'Mo', 'Tue', 'w',  2, 3, 3 ]
T= Counter(z)

for element in z:
    if T[element]>1:
        print ( "dup:" ,element, "occ:" ,T[element])
```

Comment: Thank you Remus for your time and knowledge!

Answer (score 0):

The following code check the duplicate in a list and return the duplicate.

```
def checkDuplicate(lst):
    duplicateList=set()

    for i,x in enumerate(lst,start=1):
        for y in lst[i:]:
            if x==y:
                duplicateList.add(x)
    print(duplicateList)
    return duplicateList

if __name__ == "__main__":
    lst=[1,2,2,4,4]
    result=checkDuplicate(lst)
    days={1:'Mon', 2:'Tue', 3:'Wed', 4:'Thu', 5:'Fri'}
    for v in result:
        print(days[v])
```

If you run the code above you will get results (in this example of list):

```
{2, 4}
Tue
Thu
```

Comment: Thank you Kardi really helped me!